# Is it possible to create a filedescriptor for a buffer in Node.js without creating a file in the filesystem and without hacking with child_process?

Tags: node.js

In C you can do it like this:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
    write(999, "asd", 3);
}
```

and then observe that there is *asd* in the arbitrarily chosen filedescriptor 999:

```
$ cc main.c && ./a.out 999>&1
asd
```

I have not managed to find a way to do this using Node.js standard libraries and I wonder if it's even possible without using `node:child_process` and calling the aforementioned C wrappers for Linux syscalls from there.